# Is it possible to use asciidoc with hakyll?

Tags: haskell, pandoc, asciidoc, hakyll

I followed [this tutorial](https://jaspervdj.be/hakyll/tutorials/02-basics.html) to create a basic static web page using hakyll. It includes a number of pages rendered from markdown in the `posts` directory, e.g. `2015-08-12-spqr.markdown`.

I prefer asciidoc to markdown, and tried adding an asciidoc `2018-01-23_adoc-user-manual.asciidoc` to the `post` directory.
However, `hakyll` throws an error when attempting to compile the page:

```
Initialising...
  Creating store...
  Creating provider...
  Running rules...
Checking for out-of-date items
Compiling
  updated templates/default.html
  updated about.rst
  updated templates/post.html
  updated posts/2015-08-12-spqr.markdown
  updated posts/2015-10-07-rosa-rosa-rosam.markdown
  updated posts/2015-11-28-carpe-diem.markdown
  updated posts/2015-12-07-tu-quoque.markdown
  [ERROR] Hakyll.Web.readPandocWith: I don't know how to read a file of the type Binary for: posts/2018-01-23_adoc-user-manual.asciidoc
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at lib/Hakyll/Web/Pandoc.hs:66:31 in hakyll-4.12.5.0-8ZITvFN5YREEKv6B76SCAd:Hakyll.Web.Pandoc
```

Is this problem that [`pandocCompiler`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.12.5.0/docs/Hakyll-Web-Pandoc.html#v:pandocCompiler) cannot handle `asciidoc`?
Is it possible to use `asciidoc` with `hakyll`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Current Pandoc can write Asciidoc but cannot read it: [Issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1456).

Besides, there seems no Asciidoc parser written in Haskell, so there's no pure Haskell solution.

However, Hakyll has [unixFilter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hakyll-4.12.5.0/docs/Hakyll-Core-UnixFilter.html) which can use any command which inputs from stdin and outputs to stdout. Therefore, you can call `asciidoctor` command for converting `.asciidoc` file.

Here's the step:

#### 1. Install asciidoctor

Ubuntu

`$ apt-get install asciidoctor`

Fedora

`$ dnf install asciidoctor`

Arch Linux

`$ pacman -S asciidoctor`

Ruby Gem

`$ gem install asciidoctor`

#### 2. Define pandocCompilerWithAsciidoctor

Add following code to `site.hs`

```
pandocCompilerWithAsciidoctor :: Compiler (Item String)
pandocCompilerWithAsciidoctor = do
  extension <- getUnderlyingExtension
  if extension == ".asciidoc" then
    getResourceString >>= withItemBody (unixFilter "asciidoctor" ["-"])
  else
    pandocCompiler
```

replace `pandocCompiler` in `site.hs` with `pandocCompilerWithAsciidoctor`

#### 3. Recompile

```
$ stack build
$ stack exec site rebuild
```

Note that filename have to be `2018-01-23-adoc-user-manual.asciidoc` instead of `2018-01-23_adoc-user-manual.asciidoc`, or you get error: `[ERROR] Missing field $date$ in context for item posts/2018-01-23_adoc-user-manual.asciidoc`

Comment: I have the same [problem](https://github.com/jaspervdj/hakyll/issues/600) long time ago. Keep waiting for `pandoc` to support `asciidoc` since then. Thank to you, now I can try using `asciidoc`

Comment: `unixFilter`, brilliant! I doubt I'd have been able to get asciidoc working without this helpful answer. Using `nixos` I additionally had to add `asciidoctor` to my nix packages in `stack.yaml`. Thank you!

Comment: `asciidoc-hs` is an Haskell project for parsing `AsciiDoc` as far as I've seen